# Typescript Record type with string keys infers invalid type for it's values

Tags: typescript

I'm having a simple `Record` with string keys that defined like this:

```
type Data = Record<string, string>;
```

I'm accessing values in a really simple way:

```
const data: Data = {};

const entry = data['entry'];
```

Is there a way to tell Typescript to treat these values as `string | undefined` and not simply `string`, except defining maps with `Record<string, string | undefined>`?

Strict mode is enabled, so I didn't expect to see the behavior in the real code.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOBnCwoF4oCUIGMD2ATgCYA8SwhAlgHYDmANFBdfQHwDcAsAFC8E0KUYgjgAuWKJRpMAbwC+3PsoFCWGYaIDaAcmAQKOgLpL++QfgA2EAHSX8dABShI+AGbNKGdJh0BXGmIIN1oIYh0ASl5eFhskMEsqYEcdSKgAenSoAHV8POAAfgBCHIALEChgUohCaCokKBp8KAIAWzAqSwQqcygawiIC3iA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to set the flag [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess), which is not part of `strict` because it was deemed to be potentially too disruptive.

[[Playground link with flag]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOBnCwoF4oCUIGMD2ATgCYA8SwhAlgHYDmANFBdfQHwDcAsAFAE0UoxBHABcsESjSYA3gF9uffALQsMQkQG0A5MAgVtAXUW9+SfABsIAOgv46AClCR8AM2aUM6TNoCuNYghXWghibQBKXhZrJDALKmAHbQioAHpUqAB1fBzgAH4AQiyACxAoYGKIQmgqJCgafCgCAFswKgsEKmUoKsIiPN4gA)